# Line integral using greens theorem and polar coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, greens-theorem

> The vectorfield **F** is given by $$\mathbf{F}(x,y) = (x^3 - y, x + y^3) $$ Calculate $$ \oint_C \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$$ Where C is the boundary of the region enclosed by $y = x$ and $y = x^2$ and C is oriented counter clockwise.

I cant seem to find the right bounds for $r$. I thought it would make sense to let $r$ range from $0$ to $\frac{1}{cos\theta}$ but this gives an incorrect answer. $\theta$ will of course range from $0$ to $2\pi$ and the integrand is $2r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The region bounded by $y=x$ and $y=x^2$ is described as $ 0\le \theta \le \pi /4$, and $ 0\le r\le \frac {\sin \theta }{ \cos ^2 \theta }$

Note that $y=x^2$ in polar form is $ r\sin \theta = r^2 \cos ^2 \theta.$

Comment: Why can't you use $y = x$ as the function for the upper boundary instead? Also why does using $x = 1 \rightarrow r = \frac{1}{cos(\theta)}$ for the upper bound yield the wrong answer?

Comment: Thinking in polar coordinate the region is  covered when $\theta $ runs from $0$ to  $\pi /4$ and for each $\theta$, $r$ runs from $0$ to   $ \frac {\sin \theta }{ \cos ^2 \theta }$, $y=x$ is used to find $\theta = \pi /4$